# Dense Vector Column to Sparse Vector Column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a unique situation where I need to go from a DenseVector to a Sparse Vector Column.

I am trying to implement the SMOTE technique I found here: https://github.com/Angkirat/Smote-for-Spark/blob/master/PythonCode.py
But on line 44 I had to change it from `min_Array[neigh][0] - min_Array[i][0]` to `DenseVector(min_Array[neigh][0]) - DenseVector(min_Array[i][0])` due to an error.

Once I have the DenseVector column, I need to convert it back to a SparseVector column to union my data.

I have tried the Following:

```
df = sc.parallelize([
  (1, DenseVector([0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])),
  (2, DenseVector([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 100.0])),
  (3, DenseVector([0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])),
]).toDF(["row_num", "features"])
```

```
list_to_vector_udf = udf(lambda l: Vectors.sparse(l), VectorUDT())
df = df.withColumn('features', list_to_vector_udf(df["features"]))
```

"int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DenseVector''

```
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['features'],outputCol='features')
df = assembler.transform(df)
```

"Data type struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>> of column features is not supported."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It usually doesn't make too much sense to convert a dense vector to a sparse vector since dense vector has already taken the memory. If you really need to do this, look at the sparse vector API, it either accepts a list of pairs (indice, value) or you need to directly pass nonzero indices and values to the constructor. Something like the following:

```py
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT
from pyspark.ml.linalg import DenseVector

df = sc.parallelize([
    (1, DenseVector([0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])),
    (2, DenseVector([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 100.0])),
    (3, DenseVector([0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])),
]).toDF(["row_num", "features"])

def to_sparse(dense_vector):
    size = len(dense_vector)
    pairs = [(i, v) for i, v in enumerate(dense_vector.values.tolist()) if v != 0]
    return Vectors.sparse(size, pairs)

dense_to_sparse_udf = udf(to_sparse, VectorUDT())
df = df.withColumn('features', dense_to_sparse_udf(df["features"]))

df.show()
+-------+--------------------+
|row_num|            features|
+-------+--------------------+
|      1|(10,[1,2,3,4,5],[...|
|      2|    (10,[9],[100.0])|
|      3|      (10,[1],[1.0])|
+-------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you @Psidom much appreciated. Shortly before your response I ended up coming across this post:  **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44186939/convert-dense-vector-to-sparse-vector-in-pyspark/47062913** , which is another solution as well.